# Combobox doesn't react to ".setValue()" nor ".select()"

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

This is my code:

```
comboBoxInstance.setInputPrompt("Something...");
comboBoxInstance.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
Cookie comboCookie = getCookieByName("combo");
comboBoxInstance.select((comboCookie != null) ? comboCookie.getValue() : null);

final TextField textFieldInstance = new TextField("Textfield");
textFieldInstance.setInputPrompt("Something...");
Cookie tfCookie = getCookieByName("tf");
textFieldInstance.setValue((tfCookie != null) ? tfCookie.getValue() : null);
```

The problem is that the textfield works pretty well with the "Cookie setup". Only the combobox is refusing to work like it should.

The output is like this:

[image]

I've tried to use `.setValue()` instead of `.select()` but this has pretty much the same effect. I've also made sure that both the Cookie itself and the correct value are provided.

It may help to have a look at the part where the cookie is generated:

```
Cookie comboCookie = new Cookie("combo", comboBoxInstance.getValue().toString());
cookieProcessing(costcentreCookie); //<- sets maxage and vaadin related stuff (like adding the cookie)
```

---

**Edit:**

A few points to the data flow.

I'm generating a ComboBox with a SimpleJDBCConnectionPool's SQLContainer as the data container (coming from a TableQuery). Here's the initialization (executed in the constructor) in the combobox class:

```
private void init() throws SQLException {
    this.setContainerDataSource(generateContainer());
    this.setItemCaptionPropertyId("something");
}
```

The private method `generateContainer()` returns the SQLContainer of course.

This happens if I click on a particular button which opens up a dialog. This dialog is the fragment shown in the picture above. The combobox - of course - is part of it.

What one is supposed to do now is setting his data (get an item of the ComboBox) and hit save. The save button executes the routine to store the cookies. It's the code already mentioned above (`Cookie comboCookie = new Cookie(...`).

Okay, now the user is going to open up the dialog again. It's not important whether he reloads the application or just reopens the dialog (or does something else). It's basically the same in the app.

The dialog opens up and initializes the combobox (and the textfield) once again. However, this time it's supposed to gather the data out of the stored cookies. This is were the issue happens. This works well for the textfields (there are two but I've omitted one for shortening reasons) but not for the combobox, even tough it should've the exact same data as before. Hold in mind that it's the exact same class with the exact same initialization as when we stored the cookies in the first place.

I've the vague presumption, that it has to do something how the code is stacked. Maybe it hasn't finished loading the datacontainer while trying to set the appropriated value which then can't be found.

---

**Edit2**:

I've finally managed to reveal something. The ComboBox is indeed empty when the ".select()" is executed. However, this means, that the ComboBox is left untouched (it's only kind of "linked" to the datacontainer) until someone drops down the items. As soon as this happens, the items are there and I can possibly select them.

Is it supposed to work like this? O.o Am I able to fully initialize the combobox before I do something else? Something like:

```
private void init() throws SQLException {
    this.setContainerDataSource(generateContainer());
    this.setItemCaptionPropertyId("something");
    this.gatherTheItems();
}
```

---

**Edit3 - Test with ".setImmediate(true)"**

I've changed the init to:

```
private void init() throws SQLException {
    this.setContainerDataSource(generateContainer());
    this.setItemCaptionPropertyId("SOMETHING");
    this.setImmediate(true);
}
```

This didn't change anything. The combobox is still empty:

[image: empty even with immediate set]

Comment: Please post the type of container you are using to fill combobox list. Also, Are you sure there is appropiate value in the list? Probably you just don't have the object returned by comboCookie.getValue() in the container

Comment: @kukis Thanks for your input. I've made an edit. Hope this helps :)

Comment: You put in the Cookie a value of String type comboBoxInstance.getValue().toString() . However items that are stored in your container might does not neccesarily contains Strings. Try to debug your app and see what is your itemId made of. Also try to use this method and see results https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSelect.html#containsId%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @kukis Nah, the combobox always refers to a RowID. I've already tried to instanciate an object of the type RowID. I had no success but I've learnt that the ".select" methods just casts everything to a RowID. This basically means if a "8" comes in, he casts the "8" to a RowID(8) and selects the item with this appropriated id.

Comment: @kukis I've news... Another debug has finally revealed, that the ComboBox is indeed empty when it comes to the "select". See my edit once again :D

Comment: Cool! Moving forward :) Does your combo work in Immediate mode? https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#isImmediate%28%29

Comment: @kukis Tried and failed... See Edit3 :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86854/discussion-between-kukis-and-odddev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! At first I've found a workaround which was like this:

```
    for (Iterator it_IDS = combobox.getItemIds().iterator(); it_IDS.hasNext();) {
        Object id = (Object) it_IDS.next();
        if(id.toString().equals(cookie.getValue().toString())){
            combo2.select(id);
            break;
        }
    }
```

However, I couldn't believe that this was working since it doesn't change anything at the core problem. So I've investigated, that the RowID is built via a BigDecimal and voilà:

```
    if(cookie != null) {
        combobox.select(new RowId(new BigDecimal(cookie.getValue())));
    }
```

I'm so happy right now :) Thanks for your patience kukis.

Answer (score 0):

In case you came here because you're experiencing the same issue using a BeanItemContainer as datasource, bear in mind that you must implement both `equals()`and `hashCode()` methods on the underlying class for ComboBox's `select()` or `setValue()` methods to work.

You have plenty examples on Vaadin Forum on how to implement these methods:

[ComboBox select value problem](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/458980)

[Select or ComboBox does not Show Selected Property](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/275487/275486)

[Combobox select/setValue](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/953403)